# npm's `debug` package: show logs from 2 packages

Tags: javascript, debugging

According to [the docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#browser-support), if I do:

```
localStorage.debug = 'worker:*'
```

then the 2 logs below will show:

```
a = debug('worker:a');
b = debug('worker:b');

setInterval(function(){
  a('doing some work');
}, 1000);

setInterval(function(){
  b('doing some work');
}, 1200);
```

What if I want to show logs from 2 packages that have different names?

```
a = debug('myPackage1:a');
b = debug('someOtherPackage:b');
```

What should I put here?

```
localStorage.debug = '???'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
localStorage.debug = 'myPackage1:*,someOtherPackage:*'
```

Use `,` between your string.

If you want to choose `myPackage1:a` and `someOtherPackage:b`:

```
localStorage.debug = 'myPackage1:a,someOtherPackage:b'
```